# Getting only the last row in Datagrid with datagrid.items[index]

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am trying to run a loop on a datagrid having five rows, but I am only getting the last row in the datagrid.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < mydataGrid.Items.Count; i++)
    {

        var newrow = (My_DTO)mydataGrid.Items[i];

        MessageBox.Show(newrow.FirstName.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: can I ask why cant we use source ? this looks pretty fragile

Comment: Is this your complete code? And does it run straight from the normal UI thread, and not any background thread? There are reasons this could be occurring, but it shouldn't be with the code you have posted.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this. This should help you get the row :

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGrid.Items.Count; i++)
{
    DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Each time you call `MessageBox.Show(newrow.Firstname.ToString());` you'll be overwriting the previous name.

Try:

```
String names = "";
for (int i = 0; i < mydataGrid.Items.Count; i++)
{
    var newrow = (My_DTO)mydataGrid.Items[i];
    names += newrow.FirstName.ToString());
}
MessageBox.Show(names);
```

That should just show the names one after the other with no spaces, but I'm not sure how you want to display the names, so that part is up to you.

Comment: well message box dosent over write anything does it ? may be there will be only one message box per iteration but it wont over write anything

Comment: No, there is only one instance of MessageBox.  So when you call the method to show it, you get rid of what you were showing last time and show what you have just called.  Maybe the word "overwriting" was misleading, but you only ever have one instance of MessageBox, no matter how many times you call it.

Comment: Still getting the same result i.e. the name in last row 5 times

Comment: message box will stay unless you close it and it wont get rid of last message

Comment: Do you know what the value of mydataGrid.Items.Count is?  I suspect it's just looking at the last row then.  You'll have to iterate through all of the rows in the datagrid as well, I think you can get the collection with mydataGrid.Rows.  Then for each row you need to look at the right cell.  The method you have looks at the cells on one row I believe.